# How to pass dynamic props to child component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am dynamically toggling between two components like so:

```
{this.props.firstname ? (

    <ProfileDropdown
        firstname = "SomeFirstName"
    />

) : (
     ....
)}
```

But instead of `"SomeFirstName"`, I want to pass `this.props.firstname` as the value for the `firstname` prop to the `<ProfileDropdown />` component. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Basic Rule**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx):

> We can embed any [JavaScript expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) in JSX by wrapping it in curly
>   braces.

To specify any expression inside JSX, we need to use `{}`, use it and put `this.props.firstName` inside that.

Write it like this:

```
<ProfileDropdown
     firstname = {this.props.firstname}
/>
```

Check the DOC: [**Embedding Expressions in JSX**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

**Update:**

Check this example, you will get a better idea:

```
{this.props.firstname ? (         //expression so {}
    <ProfileDropdown              //jsx
        firstname = {1 == 1 ?     //here {} to put expression inside JSX
            <div> {1+1} </div>    //inside div(JSX), so use {} again to put expression 1+1
            : <div>World</div>
        }
    />
)
```

Comment: If you notice, `<ProfileDropdown />` is already inside of a `{}` block which is why I was asking. Can't nest one `{}` block inside of another, can I.

Comment: Actually, you can.

Comment: see when you use `{}` it means some expression and on the basis of expression you are returning JSX, now when you start `<ProfileDropdown>` again inside JSX so use {} again, it can be nested upto any level :)

Comment: Wow, just tried it and it works exactly as you said. Silly me! Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @TheLearner check the updated answer, it can be upto any level, basic rule is "Inside JSX use {} to use expressions" :)